# Exception - WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Getting an exception while running the example given at 
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/10/implementing-restful-services-wso2-esb/

ESB version :- 4.8.1
DSS version :- 3.2.1

```
[2015-02-03 15:51:12,063]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:3e75d7db-d23c-4f2c-821a-c2e9ae3faa25, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.x
mlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/StudentService/003/GetStudent?registration_number=003 and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring></s
oapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

please suggest how to run this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try [How to GET a Cup of Coffee the WSO2 Way](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/get-cup-coffee-wso2-way/)
 tutorial which has comprehensive explanation for implementing RESTful service using WSO2 products (WSO2 ESB and WSO2 AS).